# Sorting with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE messages {
   chatroom_id,
   id,
   createdAt,
   senderType,
   ...,
 PRIMARY KEY ((chatroom_id), createdAt)
} WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);
```

also I have on this table secondary index on column senderType.

all the queries (until now) needed to be ordered by createdAt DESC

but now I need to do a new query like:

```
select * from messages where chatroom_id = xx
and senderType = yy
order by createdAt ASC;
```

Is there any option to create this query besides materialized view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [Cassandra code has an explicitly check](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/statements/SelectStatement.java#L1107) that no secondary indexes are used in query with `ORDER BY` inside.

IMHO you have following options:

1. create a new table & fill it from your code. It could be much faster from performance point of view than using materialized views. But this requires more coding in your app.
2. use materialized view - it's slower than explicit table, but doesn't require any additional code. But remember that MVs are still experimental in Cassandra, and you can get inconsistencies;
3. perform sorting in your application - if you don't have so much data, so you can fetch into your app & sort - in this case, the query like `select * from messages where chatroom_id = xx and senderType = xx;` will work, just return data in `DESC`...

for options 1 & 2 I would recommend to change table or MV structure to include `senderType` as part of primary key, as it will be much faster to perform, something like:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((chatroom_id), senderType, createdAt)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt ASC);
```

Comment: option 3 is not impossible because of the amount of data and thanks for the tip. I think I'll try the MV first.